# Downloading list of images

Tags: python, multithreading, http

This code downloads a list of images, each in a different thread.

I have some questions about this code:

1. I don't know how to get information about correcting downloading (sometimes thread just stopped and doesn't do anything: no error, nothing and only part of image has been downloaded). I use the next mechanism for fixing: I wait some time and if thread is alive, I write this image on need_reload file. Is there a better solution?
2. Is it good or bad this using of threads for this task?
3. Are parts of my code not "pythonic"?

---

```
import os
from threading import Thread
import urllib
import requests


def write_to_failed_image_urls_file(file_name, image_url, failed_image_urls_file):
    """
    Check image in file and write it if need
    :param file_name: image file name
    :param image_url: image URL
    :param failed_image_urls_file: name of file with fails
    :return: None
    """
    with open(failed_image_urls_file, 'a+') as need_reload:
        need_reload.seek(0)
        lines = need_reload.readlines()
        founded = False
        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith(image_url):
                print('File is here')
                founded = True
                break
        if not founded:
            need_reload.write(image_url + "," + file_name + '\n')


def write_response_to_file(response, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=2048):
            f.write(chunk)


def load_image_chunk(image_url, file_name, dir_):
    """
    Loading image by URL
    :param image_url: URL of image
    :param file_name: destination file name
    :param dir_: destination directory
    :return: None
    """
    r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        try:
            write_response_to_file(r, file_name)
        except OSError as err_:
            print(err_.__str__(), 'try redownload...')
            file_name = os.path.join(dir_, file_name.split('=')[-1] + '.jpg')
            write_response_to_file(r, file_name)
    else:
        print(r)


def load_images(image_url_list, dir_, failed_image_urls_file, delay=5):
    """
    loading list of images
    :param image_url_list: list of image urls
    :param dir_: destination dir
    :param failed_image_urls_file: name of file with unsuccessful urls
    :param delay: delay for thread
    :return:None
    """
    abs_failed_image_urls_file = os.path.join(dir_, failed_image_urls_file)
    if not os.path.exists(abs_failed_image_urls_file):
        with open(abs_failed_image_urls_file, 'w') as _:
            pass
    for image in image_url_list:
        f = os.path.join(dir_, image.split('/')[-1])
        t = Thread(target=load_image_chunk, args=(image, f, dir_))
        t.start()
        t.join(delay)
        if t.isAlive():
            print('Bad, bad thread!')
            if abs_failed_image_urls_file is not None:
                write_to_failed_image_urls_file(f, image, abs_failed_image_urls_file)
```

Comment: Threads should be fine for the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is pretty good code!  I have only a few minor suggestions:

1. Rename `image` and `images` to something that makes clear they are URLs, not files, not `numpy ndarrays`, and not any other format.  Maybe `image_url` and `image_url_list`?  The first time I read the code I didn't know what they were.  Your docstrings are good, but IMO, its even more Pythonic to have your code speak for itself (with docstrings present as backup obviously).
2. It took me several times of reading the code to figure out exactly what `need_reload_file` is.  Could you name it to be more descriptive?  Maybe `failed_image_urls_file` or something?
3. Web programmers might know what various request status codes mean, but in case a web noob like me reads your code, a comment explaining the meaning of `r.status_code == 200` would be helpful.
4. I don't understand the `file_name.split('=')[-1]` bit.  What constraint are you assuming about the structure of file names?

Comment: Even better would be to use the constant [`requests.codes.ok`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes)

Comment: 1,2, 3 (thank you, Dunno) You're right, fixed. 4 is a type of crutch, it's wrong but work solution, now I'm thinking how to do it better, the problem is on the next: some sites (one on my practice) have URLs with symbols which forbidden on OS path (" * : < > ? \ / | ) this code fixes it (only for one site which I have).
P. S. "IMO" is it "IMHO" or something else?

Comment: IMO = in my opinion.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid duplicated logic. For example you have these lines duplicated:

> ```
> with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
>     for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=2048):
>         f.write(chunk)
> ```

It would be good to move this to a helper function.

---

This is not Pythonic:

> ```
>     f = open(abs_need_reload_file, 'w')
>     f.close()
> ```

This is better:

```
with open(abs_need_reload_file, 'w') as _:
    pass
```